# Slurm - How to run a list of jobs n by n?

Tags: cluster-computing, jobs, slurm

I have a list of jobs that I must run on a cluster monitored by slurm :

```
srun job_1
srun job_2
srun job_3
...
```

I want to run these jobs 6 by 6 and I am not sure about the proper way to do it.
Thanks in advance.